# HorizontalListView and SetSelection

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am using a HorizontalListView that is provided here:

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.HorizontalListView

I am trying to programmatically select an item in the list and have it display, much like SetSelection in the normal listview.  When I try SetSelection on the HorizontalListView it does not appear to work.

I was wondering if anyone has used this control and been able to get it to work?

Before I go looking through the code, I was checking to see if anyone has done this before and maybe I am just missing something.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation of `SetSelection` only works when `Snap` is true. You can try set `CurrentScreen` to your desired screen and then call `SnapToDestination`, that might work for you.

Comment: I tried SetSelection but it did not seem to work.  I did set Snap to true as per the comment in the HorizontalListView code.  Basically I have two buttons on to scroll left and one to scroll right.  I put the following in my Click handler for the two buttons: int nItem = _horiListView.CurrentScreen; and then _horiListView.SetSelection(nItem++);

Comment: Also, I did not see a SnapToDestination Method and CurrentScreen is read-only.

Answer (score -1):

I have find the answer,you can see it [here](http://gist.github.com/httpdispatch/8953995),user the method scrollToIndex